# Gatsby Plugin Image - Eager loading not functioning with image slider

Tags: gatsby

I am attempting to build an image slider using Gatsby JS (SSG) and framer motion. I am running into an issue where images which are not visible on the page (all tabs aside from tab 1) are not being pre-rendered, despite GatsbyImage being provided with the loading="eager" prop.

I have built an image provider to query for images in the image slider:

```
const ImageProvider = ({ fileName, alt, imgStyle, style, loading, placeholder }) => {

    const { allImageSharp } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        {
            allImageSharp {
                nodes {
                    parent {
                        ... on File {
                            base
                        }
                    }
                        gatsbyImageData
                    }
                }
            }
    `)

    const image = allImageSharp.nodes.find(node => node.parent.base === fileName).gatsbyImageData;

    if (!image) return null;

    return (
        <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={alt} imgStyle={imgStyle} style={style} loading={loading} placeholder={placeholder} />
    )
}

export default ImageProvider;
```

Here is the image slider:

```
export const TabSlider = ({ 
    tabs,
}) => {
    const [[page, direction], setPage] = useState([0, 0]);

    const elementRef = useRef(null);
    const elementSize = useElementSize(elementRef);

    // We only have 3 images, but we paginate them absolutely (ie 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) and
    // then wrap that within 0-2 to find our image ID in the array below. By passing an
    // absolute page index as the `motion` component's `key` prop, `AnimatePresence` will
    // detect it as an entirely new image. So you can infinitely paginate as few as 1 images.
    // const imageIndex = wrap(0, images.length, page);

    const paginate = (newDirection) => {
        setPage([page + newDirection, newDirection]);
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <ImageProvider style={{ width: "100%" }} alt="" loading="eager" placeholder="none" />
            <AnimateSharedLayout>
                <TabsContainer>
                    <TabsHeader>
                        {tabs.map(({ title }, i) => {
                            const isActive = i === page;
                            return (
                                <TabItem
                                    key={i}
                                    className={isActive ? "active-header" : ""}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        // set page and determine which direction we're going
                                        setPage([i, i - page]);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <TabHeaderContainer>
                                        <TabHeader>{title}</TabHeader>
                                    </TabHeaderContainer>
                                    {isActive && (
                                        <Underline as={motion.div} layoutId="underline" />
                                    )}
                                </TabItem>
                            );
                        })}
                        <UnderlineBg />
                    </TabsHeader>
                </TabsContainer>
                <ContentContainer>
                    <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
                        <Section
                            as={motion.section}
                            ref={elementRef}
                            key={page}
                            custom={direction}
                            variants={variants}
                            initial="enter"
                            animate="center"
                            exit="exit"
                            transition={{
                                x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 300, damping: 30, duration: 2 },
                                opacity: { duration: 0.2 }
                            }}
                            drag="x"
                            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
                            dragElastic={1}
                            onDragEnd={(e, { offset, velocity }) => {
                                const swipe = swipePower(offset.x, velocity.x);

                                if (swipe < -swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
                                    paginate(1);
                                } else if (swipe > swipeConfidenceThreshold) {
                                    paginate(-1);
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <Background height={elementSize.height} />
                            <Wrapper>
                                <SlideContainer ref={elementRef}>
                                    <CopywritingContainer>
                                        <H2Header>{tabs[page].header}</H2Header>
                                        <Text>{tabs[page].text}</Text>
                                    </CopywritingContainer>
                                    <ImageContainer>
                                        <ImageProvider fileName={tabs[page].imageFilename} style={{ width: "50%" }} alt="" loading="eager" placeholder="none" />
                                    </ImageContainer>
                                </SlideContainer>
                            </Wrapper>
                        </Section>
                    </AnimatePresence>
                </ContentContainer>
            </AnimateSharedLayout>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

I can't see where I am going wrong here and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox or adding some logs to see where's the issue? Or adding more parts of the slider? There's an `Image` component but the slider has an `ImageProvider`, are they the same?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I'm unable to pull together a working CodeSandbox, but I have provided the full code for the image provider and tab slider components.

I have noticed that this issue occurs on any images which are not visible on the screen. I built another component which switched between two images based on a boolean state value and the second image would always pop in after a delay, despite loading="eager" being hardcoded into the GatsbyImage component of my ImageProvider.

Comment: I can see that with Gatsby's cache being cleared the image is not pre-rendered and is being downloaded for the first time when it becomes visible on the screen.

Comment: @FerranBuireu do you know if it is possible to pre-render an image from a component which is not yet part of the vDOM?

Comment: It should be possible. Try delegating that responsibility to the slider dependency rather than the Gatsby image

Comment: @FerranBuireu Apologies, I don't understand what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear to be possible using gatsby-plugin-image at this current time. Achieved by using traditional HTML image tags.